# Hide Menu options in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have been looking for ways to hide the below links from my SharePoint site when we make it live (for everyone except admins - groups are created on AD ) but unfortunately, I can't find any option to do it. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on a modern SharePoint site -

1. you can edit the navigation links and enable Audience Targeting
2. then for each link you'll need to edit and add M365/Security groups

[image]

Here is a reference document - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca